# Javascript Front-end is not completing Axios post request

Tags: javascript, express, axios

I have a react front-end that is calling my node.js API to get data from a third party API (the third party api only accepts requests from the backend), and my axios.post request stays undefined, also I can't get pass the asynchronous request, it seems like it's not telling the front end is resolved or not sending a response.

This is the front end code:

```
/* eslint-disable import/no-anonymous-default-export */
import axios from "axios";
require("dotenv").config();

let myAPI = axios.create({
  baseURL:"my api url",
});

export default {
  authAPI: async () => {
    try {
      const response = await myAPI.post("auth/token");
      console.log(response);//it never gets to this console
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);//it never gets to this console
    }
  },
};
```

And this is my API code, (the back-end receives a response with status 200 and with all the data I need):

```
import axios from "axios";
import express from "express";

const app = express();
const port = 3004;

axios.defaults.baseURL = 'third-party API url';
axios.defaults.headers.post['accept'] = 'application/json';
axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';

const instancePost = axios.create({
});

app.post('/auth/token', (req,res) => {
  instancePost.post('auth/token', {
    username: 'username',
    password: 'password',
    ttl: '0'
  })
  .then((response) => response)
  .then((response) => {
    console.log('Success!');
  })
  .catch( (error) => {
    error
    console.log('error')
  })
  
})

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`));
```

This is how my network tab looks:
[image: network tab on google chrome developer tools]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I see you need to send the response from back end and you are not sending anything only calling another service

example of how to send things to the front end

```
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send("POST Request Called")
})
```

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/express-js-app-post-function/

Comment: It worked, I had to add also some cors headers to the response but that's outside of the scope of the question. Anyways, ty!